# selenium, webdriver.page_source not refreshing after click

Tags: python, selenium, web

I am trying to copy a web page's list of addresses for a given community service to a new document so i can geocode all of the locations in a map. Instead of being able to get a list of all the parcels I can only download one at a time and there are 25 parcel numbers limited to a page. As such, this would be extremely time consuming.

I want to develop a script that will look at the page source (everything including the 25 addresses which are contained in a table tag) click the next page button, copy the next page, and so on until the max page is reached. Afterwards, I can format the text to be geocoding compatible.

The code below does all of this except it only copies the first page over and over again even though I can clearly see that the program has successfully navigated to the next page:

```
# Open chrome
br = webdriver.Chrome()

raw_input("Navigate to web page. Press enter when done: ")

pg_src = br.page_source.encode("utf") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_src)

max_page = 122 #int(max_page)

#open a text doc to write the results to

f = open(r'C:\Geocoding\results.txt', 'w')

# write results page by page until max page number is reached

pg_cnt = 1 # start on 1 as we should already have the first page
while pg_cnt < max_page:
    tble_elems = soup.findAll('table')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(tble_elems))
    f.write(str(soup))
    time.sleep(5)
    pg_cnt +=1
    # clicks the next button
    br.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='next button']").click()
    # give some time for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)
    # get the new page source (THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING)
    page_src = br.page_source.encode("utf")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_src)

f.close()
```

Comment: After the statement `br = webdriver.Chrome()` you don't load a page into Chrome before you make soup out of the contents of the page with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I navigate to the page after the browser is open. I excluded the raw_input part of the code in my original post. It's there now.

Comment: Where is that in the code?

Comment: @Bill Bell right after br = webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: No. (a) To load a page into `br` you would use its `get` method: for instance, `br.get('http://bbc.co.uk')`. (b) Loading a page into an instance of a browser has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup. (c) Using `raw_input` without capturing its result gives you nothing. If you want the user to give you a url then you'd have to use a statement like, `url = raw_input("url, please")`. Since you seem to know xpath I suggest you leave out BeautifulSoup and use just selenium.

Comment: @Bill Bell I initially used br.get and it didn't copy the page results, only the contents of the login page. Hence I'm using br.page_source. The prompt is just a stall to get the current url where I need it. Once the page source is captured by br.page_source I'm using BeautifulSoup  to get only the text elements (the table of addresses) as the additional tags make the output file twice as big.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
The problem i think is because some javascripts are not completely loaded.
All you need is wait till the object is loaded.Below code worked for me

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        delay = 10 # seconds
        try:
            myElem = WebDriverWait(drivr, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'legal-attribute-row')))
        except :
            print ("Loading took too much time!")
```